# Spring Security OAuth ResourceIds in ClientDetailsServiceBuilder.ClientBuilder?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

The [ClientDetailsServiceBuilder.ClientBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/builders/ClientDetailsServiceBuilder.ClientBuilder.html#resourceIds(java.lang.String...)) has a [resourceIds(String...)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/builders/ClientDetailsServiceBuilder.ClientBuilder.html#resourceIds(java.lang.String...)) method.  However there's no Javadoc for it.  Anyone know what the resource ids are for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `resourceId` in Spring maps to the [Audience](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-tschofenig-oauth-audience-00.html) of OAuth2 spec.

For example when using it with JWT, the Authorization server puts Audience value (claim) inside JWT. And when that JWT is passed to Spring Security it will validate that value against the value(s) that you specified via `resourceIds`. It if it does not match Spring will reject that JWT token.

Comment: OK - So this would also correspond to the `aud` claim in the openid-connect `id_token`?

Comment: Most likely it will. I know for sure that Spring expects `aud` claim in JWT token and will fail it is not set.